# Java Stream collect method

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

When using String::new as the Supplier of collect method, i saw the output is not collected and return nothing at the end.

If using StringBuilder, then works fine.

Why String::new can't do collect?

```
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g");

String collect = list2.stream().collect(String::new, (res, elem) -> {
    res = res.concat(elem);
    System.out.printf("res=%s, elem=%s\n", res, elem);
}, (res1, res2) -> {
    System.out.printf("res1=%s, res2=%s\n", res1, res2);
});
System.out.println("collect=" + collect);
```

Output:

```
res=a, elem=a  
res=b, elem=b  
res=c, elem=c  
res=d, elem=d  
res=e, elem=e  
res=f, elem=f  
res=g, elem=g  
collect=
```

Comment: What is the output you are expecting? Also what is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: @NicholasK I am expecting all string in list concat together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are immutable. The 2nd parameter of collect method is `BiConsumer<R, ? super T> var2` and wont return anything to `collect`.
This simple code snippet will help.

```
String collect = "hello";
collect.concat("world");
System.out.println(collect);
```

Output: `hello` and not `helloworld`

To achieve concat, use can use `collect(Collectors.joining(",")`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thx for pointing the consumer parameter which simply takes 1st supplier and does operation. The result of concat will not be used anywhere.

Comment: It’s worth pointing out that the difference between `stream.reduce("", String::concat)` and `stream.collect(Collectors.joining())` resp. `stream.collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append).toString()` is exactly the difference between [Reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Reduction) and [Mutable Reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction); the operations are equivalent but exhibit different performance characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

The second and third parameters of the collect method are consumers: in order to use the usefully, you need to be able to mutate the parameters.

You can't do this with String because it is immutable. You are simply reassigning the lambda parameters.

Use the `joining` collector instead.

Comment: Didn't fully understand why String immutable causing this behavior. But reassign can produce new string also?

Comment: @michael reassignment is not mutation, in the same way that moving house is not the same as building an extension even though you end up with a different house at the end. You can't mutate a string, and collect needs mutation.